# extern class: undefined reference when porting from gcc 3.x to 4.x

Tags: c++, class, reference, undefined, extern

I'm porting some hideous legacy C++ code from gcc 3.x to 4.x
There's a construct that look like this in a header file:

```
extern class ErrorLog
{
   . . .
} error_log, debug_log;
```

Under 3.x it compiles and works fine, but under 4.x I get lots of errors of the form

```
undefined reference to `error_log'

undefined reference to `ErrorLog::log(ErrorLog::LogAttr const&, char const*, ...)'
```

Comment: Where is ErrorLog::log implemented? Where is the actual definition of error_log? Sounds like your makefile changed, and you're missing one .cpp file.

Comment: ErrorLog's methods and the instance error_log are implemented elsewhere in ErrorLog.cc. That is getting built and linked. The same code links OK with the 3.x compiler

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to a [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46589) I submited to GCC a while back. The question is, does this define a type `class ErrorLog` or not? I suggest you separate the definition and the declarations, like this:

```
class ErrorLog{...};
extern ErrorLog error_log, debug_log;
```

Presumably `class ErrorLog` is defined somewhere else too -- ideally you should change this so that it's only defined once.

Comment: I tried separating the definition and declaration, but no joy. I'll take another swing at it.

Comment: What happened when you did separate them?  Did you get a compiler/linker error?  What error?

Comment: The same thing happened. No difference at all. The errors show up in the link phase. But as I say it works fine with a 3.x g++ compiler using the same source and same makefiles.

Comment: It looks like the linker is not matching this definition of `class ErrorLog` with the definition used where `error_log` and `debug_log` are defined. So make sure that `class ErrorLog` is only defined once, and then get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

Extern is a declaration, not a definition.  Therefore, you are only declaring the *name* `error_log` and `debug_log`, but not allocating a memory location for them.  You need to have the definition of those variables somewhere else (probably in a .cpp file).

It may be enough to do this in a source file that includes the header file you mention:
`ErrorLog error_log, debug_log;`

Having the entire class definition in the extern declaration is odd though.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the hang of whatever markup method this site uses. Forgive me.

There is a separate file ErrorLog.cc

#include "error.h"

   ErrorLog error_log = ErrorLog(ROOT_LOGGER_ID);`
   ErrorLog debug_log = ErrorLog(ROOT_LOGGER_ID);`

   void ErrorLog::log (const int level, const char* fmt, ...)
   {
   ...
   }

Comment: For some reason it's eating my new lines. 

`#include "error.h"
ErrorLog error_log = ErrorLog(ROOT_LOGGER_ID);
ErrorLog debug_log = ErrorLog(ROOT_LOGGER_ID);` 
`void ErrorLog::log (const int level, const char* fmt, ...) { ... }`

Comment: in comments, you can't make new paragraphs... only in the original question and in the answers.  BTW, could you please answer my question in the post above?  "What happened when you separated them?..."

Comment: Separating the class definition and extern object declarations made no difference. I think I need to try and build a simple test case.

Comment: yes.  I also think I'm missing some relevant information...  From what I've seen, the solution that TonyK posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be a simple linker ordering problem. The error_log definition was in a library listed early in the command line, but wasn't used until later on. The 4.x linker must not keep track of defined symbols the way that the 3.x linker does. Adding -Xlinker --whole-archive at the start resolved the problem, though naturally it bloated the object.

Changing the ordering would work too, but the set of archives is automatically generated, so that's more difficult without radically rewriting the Makefile.